Do MediaPipe pose_world_landmarks require scaling based on camera distance?
I'm using MediaPipe's Pose solution, which provides pose_world_landmarks as 3D coordinates of body landmarks. I've read that these coordinates are relative, and they might use the hip landmark as the origin to give a sense of depth.
However, I'm unsure if these landmarks need to be scaled based on the distance between the subject and the camera. My understanding is that the relative distances of the landmarks change with the camera distance, potentially affecting the perceived depth.
My questions are:
Do I need to scale the pose_world_landmarks based on the distance to the camera to get accurate 3D positions?
If scaling is necessary, what are the best practices to calculate and apply the scaling factor dynamically as the camera distance changes?
Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

It's better to ask this question in related forums
